# Wifi getting disconnected frequently

Tags: wireless, disconnect

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and my laptop Wifi is getting disconnected from the Access point frequently(whenever I keep it is suspend mode etc). I have to restart the laptop to again connect to Wifi.

I have checked the power management parameter, which is OFF. So any solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: You need to provide hardware information.  There are many questions currently with very similar issues so look for one that may give you some hints.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Please have a lookin [here first](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and then [edit] your question and add all relevant Wi-Fi info so that we can do a proper diagnostic.  **;-)**
  Then leave a comment @Fabby

Comment: uploaded at http://paste.ubuntu.com/23576510/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed drivers for your Network Card.
As you have `rtl8188ee` you can follow this link to install drivers for your network card https://medium.com/@elmaxx/rtl8821ae-wifi-drivers-in-ubuntu-16-04-4c1286524afa.